# Fill a dataframe column based on a common pair of values with another dataframe

Tags: r

I have the dataframe `dtshp`

```
id=c(0,0)
long<-c(140.9619,140.9626   )
lat<-c(-35.79979,-35.77946)
order<-c(1,2)
hole<-c(FALSE,FALSE)
piece<-c(1,1)
group<-c(0.1,0.1)
dtshp<-data.frame(id,long,lat,order,hole,piece,group)
```

and the dataframe `dt`

```
Town<-c("WATSONIA","NORTH MELBOURNE")
lat<-c(-35.79979,-35.77946)
long<-c(140.9619,140.9626)
pop<-c(1232131,213312)
dt<-data.frame(Town,lat,long,pop)
dt["id"] <- NA
```

How could I fill the values of `dt$id` with the values of `dtshp$id` when they have common pair of `lat` and `long`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
  left_join(dtshp, by = c("Longitude" = "long", "Latitude" = "lat"))
```

This will create columns in the merged data frame for `id.x` and `id.y`, since both data frames have a column for `id`. You could remove it from the `dt` data frame first, or use `mutate`/`transmute`/`select` after joining to choose the columns you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
dt$id <- dtshp[dtshp$long == dt$long & dtshp$lat == dt$lat,]$id
```

which gives:

```
           Town       lat     long     pop id
       WATSONIA -35.79979 140.9619 1232131  0
NORTH MELBOURNE -35.77946 140.9626  213312  0
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this answer; what if the two data frames are of different sizes? Also what if the matching rows don't appear in order.